# retrieve facebook birthday returns (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

i'm trying to retrieve the current users birthday through FBRequestConnection. i've successfully retrieved id, name and gender, but birthday just returns null. Why and what can i do in order to get the current users birthday? do i need some kind of permisson?

```
        [FBRequestConnection
         startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSString *facebookId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
                 NSString *facebookName = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
                 NSString *birthday = result[@"birthday"];
                 NSString *gender = result[@"gender"];

               NSLog(@"%@", birthday);

             }
         }];
```

Comment: Have they provided a birthday?

Comment: yes i've logged in with my own account and i have provided one

Comment: Did you ask for birthday permission?

Comment: ehhm not really? how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-loginButton.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2+100, 250, 20);
loginButton.readPermissions=@[@"email",@"user_birthday"];
```

try to add code above.